# ng-change on select throwing an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-change

**HTML**

```
            <tr dir-paginate="sale in payments | itemsPerPage: 6">
                <td>{{sale.date}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.transaction_id}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.artist_details.seller_num}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.artist_details.name}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.exc_vat}} Kr</td>
                <td>{{sale.total_price}}</td>
                <td><select ng-change="released()" ng-options="released.item  for released in releasedSeller.options" ng-model="released" ></select><span>{{released.item}}</span></td>
            </tr>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 $scope.released=function() {
        console.log('pending');
    }
    $scope.releasedSeller = {
        options : [{
                item: 'Pending'
                }, {
                item: 'Released'
            }]
    }
```

I am using ng-change to call a function in selectbox. but i can get the options data,it is wrapping the controller, i am getting the payments data here from the controller.i am using the controller by mentioning in app.js (ui-router) but when i select some option, it is throwing an error as below.

```
angular.js:13236 TypeError: v2.released is not a function
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14086), <anonymous>:4:215)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question adding more code please? Maybe you didn't set the ng-controller for that element but without more code, I can't be sure

Comment: Maybe you've overwritten the $scope.released to some other type. Please share your html and controller.

Comment: have you changes the alias of $scope as v2 in your controller as v2.released is showing error.please add the code.

Comment: i have edited the question please check

Comment: one thing to make me sure , whether controller is wrapped or not is `$scope.releasedSeller` data is after the function, but the data is getting in select box but not the function is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are binding the selected value in "released" variable which will create a new varialbe in scope and overwrite the old "released" (function) you have written in the controller.

**Wrong way :**

ng-change="released()"

ng-model="released"

**Right way :**

ng-change="released()"

ng-model="selectedReleased"

```
<select ng-change="released()" ng-options="released.item  for released in releasedSeller.options" ng-model="selectedReleased" ></select>
```

I guess this is what causing the error.

Comment: Yes, this is what causing the error, Thank you. it worked now

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure your controller wraps the html code
- Check if your code looks like this.
- Make sure your app/controllers are included in your index.html

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    'name': 'a'
  }, {
    'name': 'b'
  }, {
    'name': 'c'
  }, {
    'name': 'd'
  }];
  $scope.showSelected = function() {
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.itemModel;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <select ng-options="item.name for item in items" ng-change="showSelected(item)" ng-model="itemModel"></select>
    <h5> Selected item: {{selectedItem}}</h5>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes , it look like this only, controller wrapped the html code because all the other things are working. yes, the controller is included

Answer (score 0):

I think your are using ng-controller as syntax so this error is coming v2.released is not a function

Change v2.released to just released in your html file

Comment: i am not using v2.released here, please check the above code. i am using just released

Comment: code looks good and clean ,I wonder there must be v2 in your code

Comment: i am sure, there is no v2 in my code. i have just posted my code directly here

Comment: v2 is actually referenced by the parser as current scope.